# How to use dynamically built PK in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, primary-key

I've been Googling and searching around SO for a while now but can't seem to find the specific answer to my question. I'm attempting to build a stored procedure that will drop a primary key from a specific table when I call that 
table name. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropPrimaryKeys
    @dbname varchar(max),
    @schema varchar(max),
    @tablename varchar(max)
AS
    DECLARE @constraint varchar(max)
    SET @constraint = 'PK_' + UPPER(@tablename)

    EXECUTE ('alter table ' + @dbname + '.' + 
     @schema + '.' + @tablename + '     drop constraint ' + @constraint)   
GO

EXEC DropPrimaryKeys 'my_database', 'dbo', 'my_table'
```

When I run a `SELECT` statement instead of the `EXEC` in my stored procedure to return just the values for @schema, @tablename, @dbname, and @constraint, all the variables appear as expected. But, when I run the script, it does not seem to recognize my Primary Key name as the value held by the @constraint variable:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   'PK_PURCHASEORDER' is not a constraint.
>
> Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

I'm not sure why it's not recognizing the PK name. I've been able to successfully run this script when it's not within a stored procedure. I only seem to get this error as soon as I try to run an EXEC on it. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: If I may ask, how is it you find yourself in the unhappy position not only of having to drop primary keys regularly, but so much so that you want a procedure to do that not just for one particular table, but for any table?  The code can be written, surely.  But if I were faced with it, I would question if that's really the road I want to be on. (I have dropped keys on occasion for bulk-loading purposes, but the benefits are not nearly as great as the documentation suggests.)

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden you are right. I am unfortunately having to do this so that I can bulk load specific tables.

Comment: Then disable the primary key index. [MSDN - Disable Indexes and Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @clifon_h. I disabled the index and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Constraint name you are concatenating is might be the problem.
Pick constraint name from Meta data tables.

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE DropPrimaryKeys
      @dbname varchar(max)
    , @schema varchar(max)
    , @tablename varchar(max)

    AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @constraint varchar(max)
--SET @constraint = 'PK_' + UPPER(@tablename)
SELECT @constraint =name FROM SYS.key_constraints 
WHERE OBJECT_ID(@tablename)=parent_object_id


EXECUTE ('alter table ' + @dbname + '.' + 
     @schema + '.' + @tablename + '     drop constraint ' + @constraint)   
END
GO
```

Comment: The script does not save the primary key script which could be needed if the script incorrectly was run on another table. In other words, it may be unsafe